# Hide/show a widget with a menu checkbutton using [pack info]

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to save the info of the frame I want to hide from a menu checkbutton. I get the following error:

```
extra option "-in .mainframe -anchor center -expand 0 -fill x -ipadx 0 -ipady 0 -padx 0 -pady 0 -side top" (option with no value?)
    while executing
"pack $w $winfo"
    (procedure "cmd_toggle" line 9)
    invoked from within
"cmd_toggle .mainframe.l1"
    (menu invoke)
```

Am I using pack info the wrong way?

```
package require Tk
package require Ttk

# Menu
menu .menu
menu .menu.m1
.menu add cascade -menu .menu.m1 -label "menu1"
. config -menu .menu

# Frame + label
frame .mainframe
label .mainframe.l1 -text "blabla" -width 22

.menu.m1 add checkbutton -label "Toggle" -variable state -command [list cmd_toggle .mainframe.l1]

pack .mainframe.l1 -fill x
pack .mainframe -side left

set winfo ""   ; # save of the widget pack info

proc cmd_toggle { w } {
   global state
   global winfo

   if {$state} {
      set winfo [pack info $w]
      pack forget $w
   } else {
      pack $w $winfo
   }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Damien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not using `pack info` the wrong way but `pack` itself. `pack $w` needs a list of arguments and you are presenting one single argument that it don't know.

The solution her is, to break `$winfo` into a list of arguments with the help of the `{*}` operator.  Changing the line to this

```
pack $w {*}$winfo
```

gives the desired result.

You can use `winfo ismapped $w` to avoid the global `state` variable if you don't use a *checkbutton* (that needs a variable).

BTW: the state button is showing an inverted behaviour. You should set it to *true* at the beginning and inverting the if condition. Then if it is set, the label is shown. This is true, because the command is called **after** the variable value has been changed, so it is possible to change the value in the command.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your answer and the extra tips.